# biztalk suspend orchestration for x time

Tags: biztalk, suspend, orchestration

Is it possible to use the suspend shape in an orchestration that makes use of some kind of timer? For sequence purposes I suspend the orchestration when it is not in sequence, but if the orchestration is still suspended after 1 minute, I want to resume it.
Is this possible? I have tried using a parallel action shape with left a delay and right a suspend shape, but this doesn't work..

thx

Answer (score 4):

I strongly advise to not put this kind of timing logic inside your orchestrations. But if you need it, you'll want to use the Delay shape, which effectively pauses the processing for a specified duration.

By contrast, the Suspend shape is used to administratively suspend the orchestration in the message box, so that it could potentially be resumed at a later time.